# Conditional Cell Population

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel

First, thanks in advance.  I am a novice Excel user, always attempting to develop my skills.

Here is my scenario:
I have target cells which I want to auto populate with either a "N" or a "Y" value when certain simple condition exist.  I'll try and make it as simple as possible.

***If cell B (column) contains "7" and cells P,Q,T,U,V are not null populate cell E with "Y", otherwise "N" (for example if any of the P,Q,T,U,V are null.)***

I don't really care if I get an error if B contains any other value than 7 or if it is null.  I WOULD like to have conditional formatting on cell B if the value is "Y", but I've got that handled I think.

Thanks again.

Comment: It is better to show some Data and Tag your question Excel

Answer (score 1):

In E2 write the following formula:
`=IF(AND($B2=7,$P2<>0,$Q2<>0,$T2<>0,$U2<>0,$V2<>0),"Y","N")`

And will return True if:

- B2=7
- P2<>0
- Q2<>0
- T2<>0
- U2<>0
- V2<>0
  And the result will be Y
  If any of the above cells has a different value, And will return False and the result will be N
  Drag the formula down in column E to have the corresponding result

Comment: PERFECT!!!  Thank you for such a speedy response!